# The difference between Kimball and Inmon modelling approach

Tags: data-modeling, data-warehouse

I know that Inmon is using `up-to-bottom` and 3NF approach, while Kimball is using `bottom-to-up` and dimensional approach.

I understand the 3NF and dimensional modelling, but I really can't understand what `bottom` and `up` really mean here, I have read many materials on the internet, it seems that no one has explained clearly what they mean.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

from my understanding,bottom here means `part`, while up means `whole`, that they really mean from whole to part approach, and from part to whole approach.